# Spring Transactions cause spring-mvc integration Tests to fail

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-boot, spring-data

I am developing a spring application using spring boot 1.3

I have an MVC request handler that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = PUT, path = "/{categoryId}")
    public String update(@Valid @ModelAttribute("category") Category category, BindingResult result, @GetAttribute("currentStore") Store store, Model model, RedirectAttributes ra) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.activeCategories(store));
            return EDIT_VIEW_NAME;
        } else {
            categoryService.update(category);
            ra.addFlashAttribute("info", "Category updated successfully!");
            return redirectTo(categoryUrls.indexPath());
        }
    }
```

Here is the integration test for it

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(EstoreApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@Transactional
public class CategoriesControllerIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    @WithFactoryUser(roles = "admin")
    public void testUpdateCategoryActionWithInvalidData() throws Exception {
        //GIVEN
        String categoryId = "category_001";
        Store store = storeBuilder.getTestStore();
        categoryBuilder.createListWithStore(5,store);
        Category category = categoryBuilder.createWithId(categoryId);

        //WHEN
        this.mockMvc.perform(
                put("/admin/categories/{categoryId}", categoryId)
                        .param("name", category.getName())
                        .param("title", category.getTitle())
                        .param("status", " ")
                        .param("store", store.getId())
                        .with(csrf())
        )

        //THEN
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name(CategoriesController.EDIT_VIEW_NAME))
                .andExpect(model().attributeHasErrors("category"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeHasFieldErrors("category", "status"))
        ;
    }
}
```

some bits removed for space, but note the @Transactional annotation on top

it runs and passes without the line:

```
model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.activeCategories(store));
```

but when adding it, It gives this nasty exception, this is a bean validation exception without having any data insert operation (the validation error already handled by spring mvc and the result in the BindingResult)

```
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='{com.estore.constraints.inset}', propertyPath=status, rootBeanClass=class org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Category, messageTemplate='{com.estore.constraints.inset}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=status, rootBeanClass=class org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Category, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@ba2f4ec testClass = CategoriesControllerIntegrationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class org.commerceforge.estore.EstoreApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest=true}', resourceBasePath = '', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader', parent = [null]]].

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Category] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='{com.estore.constraints.inset}', propertyPath=status, rootBeanClass=class org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Category, messageTemplate='{com.estore.constraints.inset}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=status, rootBeanClass=class org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Category, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at org.commerceforge.estore.tests.mvc.web.integration.CategoriesControllerIntegrationTests.testUpdateCategoryActionWithInvalidData(CategoriesControllerIntegrationTests.java:296)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Category] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='{com.estore.constraints.inset}', propertyPath=status, rootBeanClass=class org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Category, messageTemplate='{com.estore.constraints.inset}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=status, rootBeanClass=class org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Category, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1227)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1293)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.findAllByStoreAndStatus(Unknown Source)
    at org.commerceforge.estore.app.service.impl.CategoryServiceImpl.activeCategories(CategoryServiceImpl.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy200.activeCategories(Unknown Source)
    at org.commerceforge.estore.app.web.mvc.CategoriesController.update(CategoriesController.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    ... 84 more
```

When I remove the @Transactional present on the class level, everything runs smoothly, so I think it is a problen in the transaction

the line:

```
model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.activeCategories(store));
```

is a wrapper around a finder query:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Category> activeCategories(Store store) {
        return categoryRepository.findAllByStoreAndStatus(store, Category.STATUS_ENABLED);
    }
```

it is just a select quert, it should never cause bean validation error

What happens is, I pass a set of invalid data to test that it will not pass, spring mvc catch the error in the BindingResult, but it seems that at the end of the test method, some sort of transaction rollback (I am not sure, just guessing) and attempt to insert data

the test pass if i remove the @Transactional annotation, but this is not practical for me as my whole test suite (950+ tests) rely on empty database , and the way i implemented it using @Transactional to rollback any changes to the data

Comment: You pass invalid data so the test must fail, but you don't want it to fail? And why do you have `@Transactional` on your test class? Because _"Rollback semantics for integration tests in the Spring TestContext Framework default to true"_. That's not true for `@Transactional`.

Comment: when passing invalid data, test should pass, as spring framework catch the validation exception, put the results in BindingResult object.

@Transactional with the rollback=true leads to deleting all data inseryed during the test, leading to clean empty database at the end of the test

Comment: `@Transactional` doesn't have a `rollback` attribute. And again: All tests should run in a transaction that's rolled back by default. There's no need to do anything explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is the flush-mode of the readOnly-query. if you are using hibernate you could set the flush-mode to COMMIT (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/QueryHints.html#HINT_FLUSH_MODE) via a org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints-Annotation on your method.

---

i can only guess at this point ... waiting for your response to my question. But i think you have a @ModelAttribute-annotated method that does the lookup for the Category-Object (something similar to http://www.javabeat.net/modelattribute-spring-mvc/)

thats why the Category-object is loaded and then modified by the data from the request, removing the status-value => Category-Object with invalid data contained in the entityManager which is flushed when the query is submitted.

the problem could also be mitigated by calling entityManager.clear() i guess, or entityManager.detach(category).

---

i guess you have an OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in place. you should be aware that every modification you do will, even in the case your controller does not explicitly call persist/update if the entity is fetched from a non-readOnly-repository-method will be written to the database unless there is a transaction rollback (through raising an exception or manually telling the transaction to rollback http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionStatus.html#setRollbackOnly%28%29)

... EDIT

ah. thats why the test works without @Transactional-rollback, because there is no transaction when the @ModelAttribute-annotated method is invoked => entityManager is closed right away and therefore the change to Category is not flushed when the query is submitted.

Comment: I added the line:
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name= org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FLUSH_MODE, value="COMMIT"))
on top of the finder method and it work :) :)
please please please, can you provide a bit of explanation, or a pointer to a reference documentation.
this will be highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: i'm not sure why it happens. it seems so that the entity manager contains a Category object with invalid data at the time the jpa query is issued, this leads to a flush of the entityMangers state (to ensure the queried data is current) ... i will try to find out why this would happen your case. in the meantime, can you post the relevant code of your categoryBuilder please?

Comment: and could you please post the code of your @ModelAttribute annotated controller-method?