# Nullpointer when testing indirectly referenced object in integration test in JHipster that is annotated with @Transactional

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, jhipster

I created a JHipster sample application using the online generator (JHipster version 7.9.3) and imported a jdl that was generated by the JDL-Studio using the default contents.

I then changed the Location Resource Integration Test (LocationResourceIT), so that I got a test case with a location that refers to a country that refers to a region. When I, starting from the location, check the id of the region, I get a null pointer exception. That is only the case if I create the location via MockMvc; if I create it via the repository, there is no problem.

See the code below, the null pointer exception occurs on the last line.

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    void createLocation() throws Exception {
        Region region = new Region();
        regionRepository.saveAndFlush(region);
        region = regionRepository.findAll().get(0);
        Long regionId = region.getId();

        Country country = new Country();
        country.setRegion(region);
        countryRepository.saveAndFlush(country);
        country = countryRepository.findAll().get(0);
        Long countryId = country.getId();

        location.setCountry(country);

        // Create the Location via MockMvc: makes last assert fail
        restLocationMockMvc
            .perform(post(ENTITY_API_URL).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(location)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        // Create the Location via repository: all asserts succeed
//         locationRepository.saveAndFlush(location);

        Country testCountry = countryRepository.findAll().get(0);
        assertThat(testCountry.getId()).isEqualTo(countryId);
        assertThat(testCountry.getRegion().getId()).isEqualTo(regionId);

        Location testLocation = locationRepository.findAll().get(0);
        assertThat(testLocation.getCountry().getId()).isEqualTo(countryId);
        assertThat(testLocation.getCountry().getRegion().getId()).isEqualTo(regionId);
    }
```

I then experimented with an example project (https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-testing) that was referenced by https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing. It contains an employee class, and I changed it so that the employee has a manager, so that I could make a similar test. That test runs without problems.

```
    @Test
    public void whenValidInput_thenCreateEmployee2() throws IOException, Exception {
        createTestEmployee("bobManagerManager");
        Employee bobManagerManager = repository.findAll().get(0);
        Employee bobManager = new Employee("bobManager");
        bobManager.setManager(bobManagerManager);
        mvc.perform(post("/api/employees").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(JsonUtil.toJson(bobManager)));
        bobManager = repository.findAll().get(1);

        Employee bob = new Employee("bob");
        bob.setManager(bobManager);
        mvc.perform(post("/api/employees").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(JsonUtil.toJson(bob)));

        List<Employee> found = repository.findAll();
        assertThat(found.size()).isEqualTo(3);
        assertThat(found.get(0).getName()).isEqualTo("bobManagerManager");
        assertThat(found.get(1).getName()).isEqualTo("bobManager");
        assertThat(found.get(2).getName()).isEqualTo("bob");
        assertThat(found.get(1).getManager().getName()).isEqualTo("bobManagerManager");
        assertThat(found.get(2).getManager().getName()).isEqualTo("bobManager");
        assertThat(found.get(2).getManager().getManager().getName()).isEqualTo("bobManagerManager");
    }
```

I see that the test runs fine if I remove the @Transactional annotation from the test.

It seems that it is not a good idea to use @Transactional in these tests, see for example: [Spring Transactions cause spring-mvc integration Tests to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722247/spring-transactions-cause-spring-mvc-integration-tests-to-fail?rq=3)

Perhaps it is a good idea leave those annotations out from the tests that are generated by JHipster?